# Understanding iterators

Tags: java, oop, iteration, iterable

I'm doing an exercise of iterators and I have 2 classes "menu" and "dish" menu.

Class Menu represents a collection of dishes from a restaurant. The implementation is done on a basic ArrayList of Dishes. The ArrayList iterator is used to iterate.

My doubt is if I can use for-each with different iterators in the same class and how.

**Menu class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Menu implements Iterable<Plat> {
    private List<Plat> plats=new ArrayList<Plat>();


    @Override
    public Iterator<Plat> iterator() {
        return new IteratorVegetaria(plats);
    }

    public Iterator<Plat> iteratorCarnivoro() {
        return new IteratorCarnivoro(plats);
    }

    public void afegirPlat(Plat p){
        plats.add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu m=new Menu();
        Iterator<Plat> c=m.iteratorCarnivoro();
        Iterator<Plat> v=m.iterator();


        m.afegirPlat(new Plat("soup",1.5,true,false,true));
        m.afegirPlat(new Plat("pizza",2.5,true,false,false));
        m.afegirPlat(new Plat("chicken",5.80,false,true,true));
        m.afegirPlat(new Plat("salad",2.5,true,false,true));


        System.out.println("Non-vegetarian menu");
        // Iteration without for-each
        while (c.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(c.next());
        }

        

        // Iteration with for-each (doesn't work and only show vegetarian dishes)
        for(Plat p: m){
            System.out.println(p);
        }


        System.out.println("Vegetarian menu:");

        // Iteration without for-each
        while(v.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(v.next());
        }

        /* Iteration with for-each*/
        for(Plat p: m){
            System.out.println(p);
        }


    }

    public class IteratorVegetaria implements Iterator<Plat>{

        private List<Plat>plats;
        private int actual=0;
        public IteratorVegetaria(List<Plat>p){
            plats = p;
        }

        // With this method we define that has next iterate as long as it finds an object that is vegetarian and adds it to the array.
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            boolean hiHaNext = false;
            int i = actual;

            while (i<plats.size() && !hiHaNext){
                if (plats.get(i).isVegetaria()) hiHaNext = true;
                else i++;
            }
            return hiHaNext;
        }

        //With this method we define that next will iterate and jump to the next position when it finds a non-vegetarian dish
        @Override
        public Plat next() {
            Plat p=plats.get(actual++);
            while (!p.isVegetaria()){
                p=plats.get(actual++);
            }

            return p;
        }
    }

    public class IteratorCarnivoro implements Iterator<Plat>{

        private List<Plat>plats;
        private int actual=0;
        public IteratorCarnivoro(List<Plat>p){
            plats = p;
        }

        // With this method we define that has next iterate as long as it finds an object that is non-vegetarian and adds it to the array.
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            boolean hiHaNext = false;
            int i = actual;

            while (i<plats.size() && !hiHaNext){
                if (!plats.get(i).isVegetaria()) hiHaNext = true;
                else i++;
            }
            return hiHaNext;
        }

        //With this method we define that next will iterate and jump to the next position when it finds a vegetarian dish
        @Override
        public Plat next() {
            Plat p=plats.get(actual++);
            while (p.isVegetaria()){
                p=plats.get(actual++);
            }

            return p;
        }
    }


}
```

**Dish class:**

```
public class Plat {
    private String nom;
    private double preu;
    private boolean vegetaria;
    private boolean apteCeliacs;
    private boolean baixCalories;

    public Plat(String nom, double preu, boolean vegetaria, boolean apteCeliacs, boolean baixCalories) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.preu = preu;
        this.vegetaria = vegetaria;
        this.apteCeliacs = apteCeliacs;
        this.baixCalories = baixCalories;
    }


    public boolean isVegetaria() {
        return vegetaria;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String missatge = "Plat{" +
                "nom='" + nom + '\'' +
                ", preu=" + preu +
                ", apteCeliacs=" + apteCeliacs +
                ", baixCalories=" + baixCalories +
                ", vegetaria=";

        if (isVegetaria()){
            return missatge+" es vegetaria";
        }else{
            return missatge+" no es vegetaria";
        }

    }
}
```

So basically when I run the code it shows this:

```
Non-vegetarian menu

Plat{nom='chicken', preu=5.8, apteCeliacs=true, baixCalories=true, vegetaria= no es vegetaria

Plat{nom='soup', preu=1.5, apteCeliacs=false, baixCalories=true, vegetaria= es vegetaria
Plat{nom='pizza', preu=2.5, apteCeliacs=false, baixCalories=false, vegetaria= es vegetaria
Plat{nom='salad', preu=2.5, apteCeliacs=false, baixCalories=true, vegetaria= es vegetaria

Vegetarian menu:


Plat{nom='soup', preu=1.5, apteCeliacs=false, baixCalories=true, vegetaria= es vegetaria
Plat{nom='pizza', preu=2.5, apteCeliacs=false, baixCalories=false, vegetaria= es vegetaria
Plat{nom='salad', preu=2.5, apteCeliacs=false, baixCalories=true, vegetaria= es vegetaria


Plat{nom='soup', preu=1.5, apteCeliacs=false, baixCalories=true, vegetaria= es vegetaria
Plat{nom='pizza', preu=2.5, apteCeliacs=false, baixCalories=false, vegetaria= es vegetaria
Plat{nom='salad', preu=2.5, apteCeliacs=false, baixCalories=true, vegetaria= es vegetaria
```

Comment: Just as an aside while reading your code, variable names like `c`, `m`, and `v` are very undescriptive and make your code harder to read.  Consider using full words and short phrases instead of single letters.

Answer (score 0):

This while loop seems broken.  The loop structure itself is a little odd and hard to read, but the problem appears to be you also never seem to update `actual`.

```
        while (i<plats.size() && !hiHaNext){
            if (plats.get(i).isVegetaria()) hiHaNext = true;
            else i++;
        }
        return hiHaNext;
```

Try something like:

```
        while (i<plats.size()){
            if (plats.get(i).isVegetaria()) hiHaNext = true;
            else i++;
        }
        actual = i;
        return hiHaNext;
```

Comment: I changed it but now nothing is prompted when I run the code

Comment: Also, in the while loops, I just changed the variable "i" for "actual", thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a case study for school, it is successfully illustrating how creating multiple iterators for a class that Implements Iterable is a bad idea :) I'm not saying it's impossible, just saying it's inadvisable.

Generally iterators are used if you want to alter the collection while iterating with

```
Iterator.remove();
```

If you try to remove an element while looping through a collection using anything other than an Iterator/ListIterator you'll blow up the ConcurrentModificationException we all love so much

You should be leveraging the Streams introduced in Java 8 (unless for some reason you are using an older version)

```
List<Plate> menu = new ArrayList();
            
List<Plate> vegetarianChoices = menu.stream().filter(new Predicate<Plate>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(Plate plate) {
                    return plate.isVegitarian();
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Plate> nonVegetarianChoices= menu.stream().filter(new Predicate<Plate>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(Plate plate) {
                        return !plate.isVegitarian();
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I see, so I shouldn't use iterators unless I want to remove some elements from a collection??                                                                                                                                      I think what they want for us to learn is how Iterator works inside using our own since we've already started with Java OOP and it's methods and libraries

Comment: Yes, as of java 8+ I wouldn't recommend using iterators for anything outside of an update loop where the Collection needs to be reduced while still looping through. Right now you are using iterators as a filter which is not what they are for.